# Upperbounds and Supremums of Subsets of R. [Solved]

Tags: elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum

(Disclaimer: This is a homework question.)

**Prove that if a subset S of $\mathbb{R}$ contains an upper bound, then this upper bound coincides with the supremum of S.**

I may be terribly misunderstanding this question. But it seems to me that the upper bound of a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is somewhat arbitrary. For example, say we look at S = $\left [0,1  \right ]$ $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}$. S is bounded above by any r $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ with r$\geq$1. But the supremum of S is obviously 1. There doesn't seem to be any reason these two should be equal, unless I'm misunderstanding the problem.

I've attempted to solve problem by using proof by contradiction:

S has a upperbound, that is $\exists$ U $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ : U $\geq$ s 
 ,$\forall$ s $\in$S.

let M = Sup(S).

The supremum is the least upper bound, that is M $\leq$ U.

Claim M = U.

Otherwise M < U $\implies$ $\exists$ x $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ such that M $\lt$ x < U.

From here we can try to show that x $\in$ S, which contradicts the supremum property of M, which would imply M = U.

But I can't seem to accomplish that.

Comment: "If a set contains an upper bound..." So, if the set contains an element which is larger than any else in the set, what is that element called? Is any other upper bound smaller than that element?

Comment: aaah okay I see. How silly of me.